# selected two values from combo box

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

if these 2 values selected from my combo box " test 1" and "test 2" next step should turn invisible and move to another step which is invisible

here is my code..i write these 2 values but i got an error.

```
Private Sub womanFacility_AfterUpdate()
 If Me.womanFacility = **"test1" and "test2"** Then
 Me.test4.Visible = False

  Else
 Me.Test4.Visible = True

End If

End Sub
```

figure the error is in my 2nd line of code start, `if Me.womanFacility` cause these 2 values if selected the next step should turn invisible

Comment: What's the error ? ...

Comment: Also you can't say "if X equals Y and Z". You have to say "if X equals Y and X equals Z". Oh, I think you probably meant to tag VBA instead of VB.NET in too.

Comment: thanks..the error id in this line...if Me.womanFacility =test1 and test2 then...

Comment: What is womanFacility?

Comment: You still didn't say what the error is. Did your compiler threaten to destroy the earth ?

Comment: An error huh? That sucks. You should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "**" is not supposed to be there (because you were thrying to BOLD your code), do as Alexandre mentioned and change your code like this:

```
If Me.womanFacility = "test1" and Me.womanFacility = "test2" Then
```